# yii user is logged in on domain.com/x but isGuest on domain.com/y

Tags: php, yii

I'm currently working in a project I toke over after other people that started this build.
When I first started the project was two different subdomains x.domain.com and y.domain.com
now we are moving it to be one domain but two sites domain.com/x and domain.com/y.
earlier the login functionality was only available on the x subdomain but now I want users too be able to be logged in on both sites.

Each site has there on main controller (xController and yController) that both extends the xyController.

If I log in on the x-site everything works great but as soon as I go to domian.com/y

`yii:app()->user->isGuest returns true`

If I go back to domain.com/x im logged in.

I can't figure out why this is happening the PHPSESSID cookie is the same for both sites.

This is my class that extends CUserIdentity:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity{
private $_id;

public function authenticate(){
    $user=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_name'=>$this->username));
    if($user === null){
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    }else{
        if($this->comparePassword($user, $this->password)){
            /** Do some other checks here **/
            $this->_id=$user->id;
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
            return !$this->errorCode;
        }
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}

public function getId(){
    return $this->_id;
}
}
```

and here is the part from the config file

```
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        'class'=>'WebUser',
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),
    ...
```

[EDIT] I found what the problem was, I had to set the id option in the config array to the same value in both configs, the id was not set in any of them before

Comment: Have you read http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/135/single-sign-on-across-multiple-subdomains/ ?

Comment: yes I've read that and I can't get it to work, when I use that approach I do now get logged anywhere. i'm just guest all the time

Comment: Are domain.com/x and domain.com/y different applications, or are 'x' and 'y' just different controller routes?

Answer (score 0):

Enable cookie-based authentication in your config:

```
'user' => array(
    'allowAutoLogin' => true,
),
```

Than configure your session component:

```
'session' => array(
    'savePath' => '/some/writeable/path',
    'cookieMode' => 'allow',
    'cookieParams' => array(
        'path' => '/',
        'domain' => '.yourdomain.com',
        'httpOnly' => true,
    ),
),
```

Make sure that */some/writeable/path* is really writable!

Finally, and this is the crucial bit with Yii (the above cookie configuration is generic PHP), the Yii application ID must be set in the config file:

```
'id' => 'yourdomain',
```

That's it!